# Slow multitasking for my Android app

Tags: java, android

I have developed an Android app that uses GPS and sqlite. The app seems to work great, but for some reason when opening the recently used apps while my app is in that list there is a significant delay. This only happens with my app and happens on my device and the emulator. Is there something special I need to do for cleanup of GPS or my database besides closing the database on destroy? Or is there something else that could cause this behavior?

**Edit**

After looking into memory usage of my app, I found that it is using about 29 MB and says there is about 9 MB free. I used the initiate GC and a nominal amount of memory was freed which leads me to believe that my app simply needs this much memory. Does this amount of memory used and this amount of memory free explain this behavior? It seems like since I am nowhere near the total amount of memory on the device, I shouldn't be running into this issue. Is this correct? If so, what else could cause this behavior?

**Another Edit**

After further testing, I have noticed that this only seems to happen on API 23 devices.

Comment: probably your app use lots of resources

Comment: Like what? There's a small sqlite DB and GPS tracking. I would think these types of technologies are efficient enough to not cause issues. Much more complex apps don't have this affect.

Comment: not sure because I don't see any code but it is a good start to check how much memory your app uses for example or check Dalvik or ART message in logcat

Comment: Monitor your app for memory usage, etc. Android Studio has improved Device Monitoring.

Comment: How much work are you doing on the main UI thread? I'm wondering if your app is slow to respond to requests from the system. Android devices don't configure swap, so simply using lots of memory wouldn't affect this -- and 29MB isn't a lot of memory on a modern device.

Comment: @fadden I'm not doing too much on the main UI thread. The biggest task is going through about 500 sqlite rows and checking them. I'm not writing to those rows though, just reading. Just to check I threw that into an asynctask and it didn't solve the issue. This really isn't what I want to do either because I want to do this synchronously so I can show results while reading them in.

Comment: What is the size of your apk file ?

Answer (score 1):

GPS costs a lot of speed, cause it most of the time drains your cell usage, wifi and GPS. This will cause the device to slow down. Other apps do not have this problem because most are not GPS based or have a phone with low memory

Comment: Is there something that I should be doing to make the GPS usage more efficient? I am currently calling removeUpdates on my location manager whenever possible. Also, the device has 3GB of memory which should be plentiful for this app seeing as it only uses about 29 MB.